# Show that convolution of two $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ functions is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution

Suppose $f, g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. I want to show that their convolution is continuous.

I can show continuity if one of the functions were in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

I have tried to approximate one of the functions, say $f$ with $f_M = f\cdot \mathbb{I}\{ |f(x)| \leq M\}$. But I have problem bounding the residual, which would be of form:

$$ \int_\mathbb{R} |f(x-z) - f_M(x-z)|\cdot |g(z)| dz$$

Any help/hint would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true. The counterexample I know is:

$f(x) = g(x) = \begin{cases}
x^{-3/4}&0<x< 1\cr
0& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

then $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f*f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-}f*f(x)=0$.

I guess you need at least one of $f$ or $g$ to be $L^{\infty}.$

Comment: $x^{-3/4}\notin L^1.$

Comment: So I'll just cut it at $1$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to have a simple way of showing that the $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f*f(x) = \infty$?

Comment: I think we can do this: Note that if $0<x<1,\ f*f(x)=\int^x_0f(x-y)f(y)dy$. Then, since $y<x$, we compute $\frac{1}{x-y}\cdot \frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{x-y}+\frac{1}{y}\right)\ge \frac{1}{x}\cdot \frac{1}{y}$ 
 and so we get $f*f(x)\ge \frac{1}{x^{3/4}}\int^x_0y^{-3/4}dy=\frac{4}{x^{3/4}}\cdot x^{1/4}=\frac{4}{x^{1/2}}\to \infty $ as $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: That's perfect! I did an underestimate with rectangles and got $1/\sqrt{x}$ too.

Comment: You really got your hands dirty then, (: How did you deal with the overlap? I imagine you fixed an $0<x<1$, took a partition and constructed rectangles under the graph of the product. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

$f*g$ is not a well defined function from $\mathbb R$ to itself, in general. For example, if $f(x)=g(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {|x|}}$for $0<|x| \leq1 $ and $0$ elsewhere then $(f*g)(0)=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can see that convolution of two continuous functions is continuous but I'm not sure how to use the uniformity of limits. I don't think approximation by continuous function is uniform on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: The point is that if you convolve two $L^1$ functions then you still get an a.e. defined $L^1$ function. This follows directly from [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality) with $p=q=r=1$.